# Segmentation Fault C++ Sundaram

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The main goal of my program is to print all the prime numbers between 2 and a limit. When I run it with limit = 35000 or even limit = 50000 it prints correctly, but when I try to run it with limit = 75000 it gives me a segmentation fault. Any idea why? And is there any thing I could do to get a better performance? (Solution based on the Sundaram Algorithm)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX 1000000



int main() {
    int vetor[MAX];
    int limite;

    scanf("%d", &limite);


    for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++){
      vetor[i] = i;
    }

    /* Marcar todos os compostos */
    for (int i = 1; i < limite/2; i++){
      for (int j = i;  j< limite/2; j++){
        long aux = i + j + 2 * i * j;
        if(aux <= limite)
          vetor[aux] = 0;
      }
    }

    /* Imprimir os verdadeiros primos, incluíndo o 2 */
    printf("2\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= limite; i++){
      if (vetor[i] != 0){
        long aux = i*2 + 1;
        if (aux < limite){
          printf("%ld\n",aux);
        }
      }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger at all?

Comment: Also, this looks like vanilla C, not C++.

Comment: this `long aux = i + j + 2 * i * j;` will surely get out of scope of MAX.

Comment: Your vector only stores "i" or "0" values. That's effectively one bit. In such cases, `vector<bool>` can be more efficient.

Comment: if i = 10; how vector<bool> store the data? vector<bool> only store "0" or "1" @MSalters

Comment: Simple, by setting `vec[10] = true;`

Comment: In this loop: for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++){
      vetor[i] = i;
    } he store "i" not "1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I changed `i`, `j` and `aux` to 'unsigned long long'. Your problem is overflow. It means your integer number became greater than maximum integer value. Hopefully `int` is not the largest integer data type. The largest is `unsigned long long`. But anyway remember that there is stil limit when you will meet this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX 1000000



int main() {
    int vetor[MAX];
    int limite;

    scanf("%d", &limite);


    for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++){
        vetor[i] = i;
    }

    /* Marcar todos os compostos */
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < limite/2; i++){    
        for (unsigned long long j = i;  j< limite/2; j++){
            unsigned long long aux = i + j + 2 * i * j;
            if(aux <= limite)
                vetor[aux] = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Imprimir os verdadeiros primos, incluíndo o 2 */
    printf("2\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= limite; i++){
        if (vetor[i] != 0){
            long aux = i*2 + 1;
            if (aux < limite){
                printf("%ld\n",aux);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Was it on the first aux? Tried with long, seems like it was not enough :)

Comment: The error happened in `vetor[aux] = 0;` line. `aux` value was something like -2234348534895

Comment: actually, the first i and j can be integers, no need to use unsigned long long, i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Type `long` (or `long int`) is an integral type that is larger than or equal to the size of type `int` .

Type `long long` Larger than an `unsigned long.`

Type `unsigned long long` Larger than `long long`.

Read this [Data Type Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define MAX 1000000



    int main() {
        int vetor[MAX];
        int limite;

        scanf("%d", &limite);


        for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++){
          vetor[i] = i;
        }

        /* Marcar todos os compostos */
        for (int i = 1; i < limite/2; i++){
          for (int j = i;  j< limite/2; j++){
            unsigned long long aux = i + j + 2 * i * j;
            if(aux <= limite)
              vetor[aux] = 0;
          }
        }

        /* Imprimir os verdadeiros primos, incluíndo o 2 */
        printf("2\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= limite; i++){
          if (vetor[i] != 0){
            long aux = i*2 + 1;
            if (aux < limite){
              printf("%ld\n",aux);
            }
          }
        }

       return 0;
    }
```